# On $\kappa$-filtrations and clubs.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filtrations

Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa$. A $\kappa$-filtration of $A$ is an indexed sequence $\{A_{\nu}:\nu<\kappa\}$ such that for all $\mu,\nu<\kappa$:

1. the cardinality of $A_{\nu}$ is $<\kappa$;
2. if $\mu<\nu$ then $A_{\mu}\subseteq A_{\nu}$;
3. If $\nu$ is a limit in $\kappa$, then $A_{\nu}=\bigcup_{\mu<\nu} A_{\mu}$;
4. $A=\bigcup_{\nu<\kappa} A_{\nu}$.

My question is why the following (Exercise II.18 in Eklof and Mekler's *Almost Free Modules*) holds:

If $\{A_{\mu}:\mu<\kappa\}$ is a $\kappa$-filtration of a set $A$ of cardinality $\kappa$, being $\kappa$ regular, there is a club $C$ in $\kappa$ such that for all $\nu\in C$, $|A_{\nu^{+}}\setminus A_{\nu}|=|\nu^{+}\setminus \nu|$, where $\nu^{+}$ denotes $\inf\{\alpha\in C:\alpha>\nu\}$.

A hint would be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Normally we use $\min$ rather than $\inf$ when talking about ordinals, and also $\nu^+$ normally indicates the smallest cardinal larger than $\nu$, rather than "the next element in the club".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, but this was the way it was written in the book so I've just written it verbatim thinking this might be the standard notation in this particular context. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $C=\{\nu<\kappa:|A_\nu|=|\nu|\}$, and show that $C$ is closed and unbounded.